# I just installed prospect mail using snap and I cannot figure out how to launch it

Tags: applications

I just installed prospect mail using snap and I cannot figure out how to launch it. I searched for information on how to launch Prospect Mail and all I found was to use Activities Overview. I don't believe this was an eOS specific answer since I cannot find any such window. Prospect does not show up in the Applications pane either.

Comment: Solved this by uninstalling the snap plugin and installing prospect-mail as a Debian package.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the snap apps executables with:

```
ls /snap/bin
```

and then

```
/snap/bin/./<name of the app you want to run here>
```